# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty when rendering partial with javascript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having this issue when i try to render a micropost with ajax in my view as i get:

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Micoposts are being created but for some reason they are nil or empty in the javascript file. I can realize there is some kind of conflict in my index view as im rendering both the post form, and a comment form for each post, so i guess maybe is something relating the variables im instantiating in my index view because when i replace in the comment form this line

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for([micropost, @comment], remote: true) do |f| %>
```

with

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for([micropost, micropost.comments.build], remote: true) do |f| %>
```

everything works but the field errors in my comment form are not being displayed

```
#posts_controller

def new
  if logged_in?
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
    @comment = @micropost.comments.build
    @feed_items = current_user.feed
  else
end

def create
  @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @micropost.save
      format.html { redirect_to root_url }
      format.js
    else
        format.html { render action: "index" }
      format.js
    end
  end 
end

# _form_micropost.html.erb

<%= bootstrap_form_for(@micropost, remote: true) do |f| %>
<% end %>

# _form_comment.html.erb
<%= bootstrap_form_for([micropost, @comment], remote: true) do |f| %>
<% end %>

create.js.erb

<% if @micropost.errors.any? %>
  $("#form-micropost-container").html("<%=escape_javascript(render('shared/form_micropost')) %>");
<% else %>
  var micropost = $("<%= escape_javascript(render(@micropost)) %>").hide().fadeIn("slow");
  $("#feed-container").prepend(micropost);
<% end %>
```

Comment: In `new.html.erb` you are calling both the partials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing all arguments explicitly:

```
#posts_controller

def new
  if logged_in?
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
    @comment = @micropost.comments.build
    @feed_items = current_user.feed
  else
end

def create
  @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
  @comment = #assign comment here

  respond_to do |format|
    if @micropost.save
      format.html { redirect_to root_url }
      format.js
    else
        format.html { render action: "index" }
      format.js
    end
  end 
end

# _form_micropost.html.erb

<%= bootstrap_form_for(micropost, remote: true) do |f| %>
<% end %>

# _form_comment.html.erb
<%= bootstrap_form_for([micropost, comment], remote: true) do |f| %>
<% end %>

create.js.erb

<% if @micropost.errors.any? %>
  $("#form-micropost-container").html("<%=escape_javascript(render('shared/form_micropost', micropost: @micropost)) %>");
<% else %>
  var micropost = $("<%= escape_javascript(render('form_comment', micropost: @micropost, comment: @comment)) %>").hide().fadeIn("slow");
  $("#feed-container").prepend(micropost);
<% end %>
```

Comment: Assigning @comment = Comment.new in microposts create action does the trick. Thanks